# How to make perfect documentation of FYP with less plagiarism?

Tags: student-motivation, computational-thinking, struggling-students

For a student of BS(CS), a supervisor wants documentation of final year project with high vocabulary and with less plagiarism, but the students write documentations on their own, without copying paste process but still there are a lot of mistakes and plagiarisms in documentation. What method should be applied to make documentation with less plagiarism and with broad vocabulary?

Comment: Are you writing as a student or as the teacher?

Comment: I am writing as a student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of literary in education is much more severe in the work of institutions where it is difficult to show individual contributions in different fields in particular. With many others, we found the evidence of literature in the last year of the undergraduate projects. This is an important part of our program. The undergraduate partnership is about 20% of the degree award. Current approaches to detecting non-original material are defective, this paper describes an alternative procedure that integrates with the Internet-based project system that combines the management, monitoring and promotion of good and fair ways. It explains the paper issues associated with the current approach, the use of natural language processing techniques to help prevent literature and its blocking, and to report some preliminary results.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, of course, the professor should teach you how to do this as part of the course. It isn't a simple or obvious task. Large companies, such as IBM and Oracle, employ documentation specialists who have special training and work with other technologists to produce the documentation.

If you were a teacher and didn't have a lot of time to teach documentation, I would recommend letting students do a first draft without much direction and then letting them revise it after giving them feedback. This would let the teacher focus comments on the actual issues that arise rather than needing to give a comprehensive course. Perhaps your teacher would agree to do that, but I'll assume not.

Another possibility that you might be able to employ, but only with the teacher's permission, would be to have pairs of teams work together to help refine each other's documentation. One team can give advice to the other on what is needed and on what problems might be seen.

But, to include a high level of vocabulary in the documentation, you should probably start with a list of terms that you want to include. You can, perhaps, have a glossary that explains them. Then make sure that their use appears in the documentation itself. Normally there are two kinds of documentation: system and user. Make sure that you know whether both are required and for either, make your vocabulary meet the needs of those who need it.

To avoid plagiarism you write like you would any academic work. If you need something that others have done, cite it and build a bibliography. If you need to quote from existing documentation, make sure that you quote properly and sparingly. Say where ideas come from (citation) and then either make short quotes from it or paraphrase the ideas from the citation in your own words.

In general, though, in writing documentation, put yourself in the mindset of the person who needs the documentation; perhaps an end user. Likewise if the documentation is to explain the internals of your project for your teacher, then give explanations in more technical terms.

Unfortunately, I suspect that you ask this question at the end of the course, when it is really too late to plan the documentation from the beginning. A larger group could have one member (two?) work throughout the project primarily as the documenter. Alternatively, you could see to documentation along the way if everyone contributes to it. Every few hours of work, document what you have. But that isn't possible if you write documentation only at the end.

You can also, perhaps use an example of professional documentation. If you are writing in Java, for example, the java doc in each class provided in the libraries begins with a conceptual level view of that class. That is technical documentation. But in addition, Oracle provides many web pages that explain how Java is actually used, not just what it is. You might use that as a guide. Similar things exist for most languages. But that should just give you an idea of the kinds of information you need to include and how to organize it. Vocabulary and plagiarism are separate issues.